# Percentage up until maximum with variable in calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, percentage

Given:

Yearly Gross: T2=((S2*13,92)+V2)

V2 is currently empty, but it should contain a maximum amount of T2*20%.

Any ideas?

Nick

Comment: I think you forgot to mention how do you calculate the Bonus Amount

Comment: That's it, it can be for example 2000, but it can never be more than 20% of total T2. So it is basically part of the given data, but is also one of the variables.

Comment: So you don't actually want to calculate V2, you just want to check whether it doesn't exceed the limit. Is that what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to do it for 3000+ lines all at once. So V2 has to be the maximum bonus amount, capped at 20% of the total in T2.

Comment: Replace `V2` with `If(V2/T2>.2, T2*.2, V2)` That's a formula that says "If V2/T2 is greater than 20% then take 20% of T2, else just use V2"

Comment: Yes, thank you for the feedback. But in this case, I still need to populate V2 myself, I would like it to be populated automatically with the maximum amounts for all of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment, but I don't have 50 points, so this is getting added as an answer.

By your responses and the way you wrote the question you are asking for a recursive formula:  The answer (T2), can only be calculated by using T2 in the formula that creates V2 which is used in the formulat that creates T2. Excel doesn't like that.
Ex: If T2 is $100, then V2 caps at $20, but then that increases T2 to $120 because T2 includes V2, so now V2 is $24, which increases T2... etc.

Otherwise, you need your "base" gross salary (not T2) to calculate the maximum bonus amount and place that value into V2.  `V2=if(("attempted bonus"/base)>.2, base*.2, "attempted bonus")`

Comment: Or if V2 truly is capped at 20% of Base+Bonus, then use .25 in the equation, due to the math:  Base*5/4= "Base+Bonus".  (Base+Bonus)*4/5=Base.